# 3D scatterplot colored by Z-Value

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, matlab-figure, color-coding

I've been googling for a while but couldn't find a solution for my problem. I am an amateur matlab user and I would like to create a 3D scatterplot, for this I have a matrix containing several points in 3D space:

```
>> size(A)

  ans =

        2511           3
```

I was able to create a 3D scatterplot using "scatter3" function, but now I am stuck a bit at color-coding the 3D points.

> > scatter3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3));

This will plot the data, but now I would like to add a color coding based on the z-Value...
The colors themself don't matter too much. It could be a rainbow spectrum or a temperature spectrum or whatever. I just would like to colorcode them to distinguish the z-Values of the points.

Can anybody help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: My answer is straight from the docs, by the way: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/scatter3.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to give some more arguments to `scatter3`.

```
scatter3(X,Y,Z,S,C);
```

`S` lets you specify areas for each markers (with a vector) or a single area for all the markers, while `C` lets you specify color.  If `C` is a vector, its values will be linearly mapped to the current colormap.  To change the colormap, call `colormap(jet)` for example.  See the documentation on `colormap`.

Sorry if that's confusing.  Short version:

```
scatter3(A(:,1),A(:,2),A(:,3),9,A(:,3));
colormap(jet); %# or other colormap
```